# Squareup Webhook - Send duplicate request

Tags: php, square-connect

I am using squareup APIs .. i setup the notification URL to my application correctlly and setup it for `PAYMENT_UPDATED`

```
// setup notifications
$data = array("PAYMENT_UPDATED");
$data_json = json_encode($data);
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/webhooks");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json),
    'Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);

echo $response  = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($response,true));
echo "</pre>";
```

and i make a payment from a mobile device then, i got a duplicate requests for the single payment withe the same data like that:

```
     {"entity_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","event_type":"PAYMENT_UPDATED","merchant_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","subunit_id":"xxxxxxxx"}
```

any help ?!

Answer (score 0):

I just started having this problem with a production app on 5/18/15 at about 5:30pm.

I log each request that comes in and perform some data manipulation after each webhook callback. My solution was to simply put a unique constraint in my database based on the entity_id received. Not a great solution, but a temporary workaround to not have everything performed 2x.

Answer (score 0):

Your duplicate webhook notifications are likely due to some kind of immediate processing effect in your workflow. For example a card transaction that you authorize and then capture would fire multiple webhooks.